# Need help Clarifying the meaning to something in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

My professor has lately been writing $\text{Re }z$ and $\text{Im }z$ for my complex analysis class and I'm confused to what this means. Could someone explain? Does it mean the real parts, so just $x$ and the imaginary parts, so just $yi$?

Comment: Why dont you ask your professor ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus This question could be valid at least for 70% of OP on MSE!

Comment: @gimusi Yes, and dont you dare use it ! Its now my standard response.

Comment: @gimusi When a person says or writes something that you don't understand, that appropriate response is to ask that person.  Maybe even interrupting a lecture to do so, though more politely asking after class, during office hours, or during the designated question period at the end of a talk.  That JesHuerta indicated that they have direct interaction with a professor indicates that they haven't even taken the simplest, most obvious step towards answering their question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I fully agree with you, it's no good to not interact during a class. Maybe many students are ashamed to ask for clarification on issues that may seem trivial while here on MSE they fell more free to ask also for simple clarifications.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Given a complex number $z=x+iy$,
$$
\text{Re}(z)=x,\quad \text{Im}(z)=y
$$

Answer (score 1):

A complex number is expressed by two **real numbers** $x$ and $y$ such that:

$$z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$$

and by definition:

- $\text{Re}(z)=x\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\text{Im}(z)=y\in \mathbb{R}$

Note also that by the definition of **complex conjugate** $\bar z= x-iy$, we have that:

- $\text{Re}(z)=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}=x\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\text{Im}(z)=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}=y\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: so when I have $f(z)= z$ Re $z$  this means that $f(z)= (x+yi)x?

Comment: The function f(z)=Re(z) is simply f(z)=x while $f(z)=zRe(z)=x^2+iyx$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = x + i\cdot y$ be a complex number.

Then $\text{Re}\ z = x$, $\text{Im}\ z = y$.